Show this process is Brownian motion
Let $U(t)=W(t)-\int_0^t\frac{W(s)}{s}ds$. Show that $U(t)$ is a Brownian motion.
I am struggling to prove that $\text{cov}(U(t),U(v))=\min\{t,v\}$. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

When $W$ is a BM then $U$ is not a BM. What makes you think otherwise? If $U$ were a BM then your formula implies that $U-W$ is a martingale of finite variation. Hence it must be zero.

@KurtG. I am not sure about your argument but I just check the definition of Brownian motions and if it satisfies then it is BM

@KurtG. $U$ and $W$ could be martingales w.r.t. different filtrations. Why should $U-W$ be  a martingale?

@geetha290krm OK. I see all your points against my two comments in that post.

$$
    \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[U(t)U(s)] &= \mathbb{E}[W(t)W(s)] - \mathbb{E}\left[W(t)\int_0^s \dfrac{W(u)}{u}du\right]\\
 &- \mathbb{E}\left[W(s)\int_0^t \dfrac{W(u)}{u}du\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t\int_0^s \dfrac{W(u)W(v)}{uv}dudv \right]
    \end{align*}
$$
Assume that $s < t$, then $\mathbb{E}[W(t)W(s)] = s$. By Fubini theorem,
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left[W(t)\int_0^s \dfrac{W(u)}{u}du\right] = \int_0^s \dfrac{\mathbb{E}(W(t)W(u))}{u}du = \int_0^s \dfrac{\min\{t, u\}}{u}du = \int_0^s du = s 
$$
Similarly,
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left[W(s)\int_0^t \dfrac{W(u)}{u}du\right] = \int_0^t \dfrac{\min\{u, s\}}{u}du = \int_0^s du + \int_s^t \dfrac{s}{u}du = s + s\ln \dfrac{t}{s}
$$
and,
$$
    \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^s \dfrac{W(u)W(v)}{uv}dudv\right] &= \int_0^t \int_0^s \dfrac{\min\{u, v\}}{uv}dudv = 2s + s\ln \dfrac{t}{s}
    \end{align*}
$$
Thus,
$$
    \mathbb{E}[U(t)U(s)] = s = \min\{s, t\}
$$

@ThànhNguyễn thank you, I was unsure at first whether I could use Fubini or not but your answer confirm my method.
